# How to check multiple sites for availability at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I wanted to write a code that will check the availability of sites using "status_code"
But in the end I got into a stupor, I do not know how to implement the verification of each site entered into the widgets
I manage to check only one site from one widget, but I need to check each one, and set a time for each site to check
I would like to know, or at least get hints on how to implement it
I will be grateful for any help

My attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox




window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x700')
window.title("SiteChecker")


def SiteCheck():
    res=int(tim1.get())
    Site_Value = txt1.get()
    Get_Response = requests.get(Site_Value)
    time.sleep(res)
    if Get_Response.status_code != 200:

        #as I understand it, you need to make a "for" loop, but I don't understand how to implement


def clicked():
    txt = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt.grid(column=0, pady=8)
    txt_row = txt.grid_info()['row']

    tim = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim.grid(row=txt_row, column=1, pady=8)






lbl1 = Label(window, text="Enter references:")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Enter the test time: ")
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl3 = Label(window, text="Availability status ")
lbl3.grid(column=2, row=1)


txt1 = Entry(window,width=18)
txt1.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=8)
txt2 = Entry(window,width=18)
txt2.grid(column=0, row=3,pady=8)
txt3 = Entry(window,width=18)
txt3.grid(column=0, row=4,pady=8)
txt4 = Entry(window,width=18)
txt4.grid(column=0, row=5,pady=8)
txt5 = Entry(window,width=18)
txt5.grid(column=0, row=6,pady=8)


tim1 = Entry(window,width=3)
tim1.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=8)
tim2 = Entry(window,width=3)
tim2.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=8)
tim3 = Entry(window,width=3)
tim3.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=8)
tim4 = Entry(window,width=3)
tim4.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=8)
tim5 = Entry(window,width=3)
tim5.grid(column=1, row=6, pady=8)

result1 = Label(window,text="status")
result1.grid(column=2, row=2, pady=8)
result2 = Label(window,text="status")
result2.grid(column=2, row=3, pady=8)
result3 = Label(window,text="status")
result3.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=8)
result4 = Label(window,text="status")
result4.grid(column=2, row=5, pady=8)
result5 = Label(window,text="status")
result5.grid(column=2, row=6, pady=8)


btn = Button(window, text="Add another site", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row = 0)

Check_Button = Button(
    window,
    command = SiteCheck,
    text='Start checking',
)
Check_Button.grid(row=0, column=2)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to sleep. If you get error code 200, then call the function again in 200ms (or the value from tim1): `root.after(200, SiteCheck())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but i am do it without time sleep you can add later

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


data_list = []

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x700')
window.title("SiteChecker")

def set_input(obj, value):
    obj.delete(1.0, "END")
    obj.insert("END", value)

def SiteCheck():
    #res=int(tim1.get())

    #time.sleep(res)
    for data in data_list:
        url = data[0].get()
        status = data[2]
        if not str(url).startswith('http'):
            continue
        print(url)
        Get_Response = None
        try:
            Get_Response = requests.get(url)
        except:
            status.config(text = 'status bad')
            continue
        
        
        if Get_Response.status_code == 200:
            status.config(text = 'status ok')

            pass
            #as I understand it, you need to make a "for" loop, but I don't understand how to implement
        else:
            status.config(text = 'status bad')

def clicked():
    txt = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt.grid(column=0, pady=8)
    txt_row = txt.grid_info()['row']
    
    tim = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim.grid(row=txt_row, column=1, pady=8)
    txt_row = tim.grid_info()['row']

    result1 = Label(window,text="status")
    result1.grid(row=txt_row, column=2, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt, tim, result1])





lbl1 = Label(window, text="Enter references:")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Enter the test time: ")
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl3 = Label(window, text="Availability status ")
lbl3.grid(column=2, row=1)

for loop in range(2 ,6):
    txt1 = Entry(window,width=18)
    txt1.grid(column=0, row=loop, pady=8)


    tim1 = Entry(window,width=3)
    tim1.grid(column=1, row=loop, pady=8)
    

    result1 = Label(window,text="status")
    result1.grid(column=2, row=loop, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt1, tim1, result1])

btn = Button(window, text="Add another site", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row = 0)

Check_Button = Button(
    window,
    command = SiteCheck,
    text='Start checking',
)
Check_Button.grid(row=0, column=2)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you at least tell me roughly how to make time?

Comment: yes so easy  --> `time = data[1].get()` you will get value of time

Comment: but i don't know why you will put time in request